# How Can I add LG Split Window Support to my android App? Is it even possible actually?

Tags: android, split, window, lg

I am making an Android app which I want to have  LG Split Window Support but there isn't any info about it being possible or not and if possible how to do it. Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting myself from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), for LG's legacy split-screen support:

> LG requires only one thing: a `<meta-data>` element in the `<application>`, with a
>   name set to `com.lge.support.SPLIT_WINDOW` and a value of `true`. It assumes that
>   your launcher activity (or activities) are suitable for showing in a split screen view.

[This sample app](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/v8.7/MultiWindow/Legacy/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) shows supporting Android 7.0+ native multi-window, plus Samsung's and LG's legacy split-screen support. The manifest shows that `<meta-data>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.commonsware.android.multiwindow"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

  <supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" />

  <application
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:resizeableActivity="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Apptheme">
    <uses-library
      android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow"
      android:required="false" />

    <meta-data
      android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
      android:value="true" />
    <meta-data
      android:name="com.lge.support.SPLIT_WINDOW"
      android:value="true" />

    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <layout android:minWidth="480dp" />
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me

Comment: Are these Samsung and LG elements still relevant in the latest (O or P) versions of Android?

Comment: @Mark: Those manufacturers should be using the native multiwindow support now. Mostly, those elements are for Android 6.0 and before.

Comment: @CommonsWare so I guess only can be removed if minSdkVersion >= 24